# Multiprocessing Pool giving TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing code and it is giving me an int not iterable error. new list is a clear list here and not an int object

```
import multiprocessing
import os
# creating a list
new_list = []
for i in range(1000000):
    new_list.append(i)

def sum_numbers(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        print(os.getpid(),number*number)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    print(p)
    result = p.map(sum_numbers,new_list)
    print(result)
```

Comment: You are misusing `p.map`.  You want `p.apply`.  Why are you using multiprocessing for this example?  Please read the documentation.

Comment: Map applies a function to each element of an iterable. Your function is being called one million times with an integer as the argument.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? Please make a [mre] including expected output. You can [edit].

Comment: Sidenote: this is shorter: `new_list = list(range(1000000))`.

Comment: Also, if you are running under Windows, every process in your pool will be re-computing `new_list` needlessly.

Comment: @wjandrea There is no need to explicitly convert the range to a list; the `map` function will explicitly do that if necessary. So the second argument to `map` can just be `range(1_000_000)`.